# How create sort option for Yii gridview custome column fields

Tags: php, gridview, yii

I want do sort for custome column fields for table fields its working fine, clinkcolumn fields or customs fields not working

```
<?php 
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', 
array(


     'dataProvider'=>$dataProviderInActive,
              'id'=>'collections-grid-inactive',
              'itemsCssClass'=>'table collections',
              'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
              'pager'=>array(
                'class'=>'CLinkPager',
                'header'=>'',
              ),
              'columns'=>array
              (
                 array(
                   'class'=>'CLinkColumn',
                   'labelExpression'=>'$data->collection_title',
                   'urlExpression'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("",array("collection"=>$data->collection_title))',
                   'header'=>'Catalog Title'
                   ),
                 array(            // display 'author.username' using an expression
                  'name'=>'Number of Images',
                  'value'=>'',
                 ),
                 array(            // display 'author.username' using an expression
                  'name'=>'Number of images used in lightboxes',
                  'value'=>'0',
                 ),
                 array(            // display 'author.username' using an expression
                  'name'=>'Number of expired',
                  'value'=>'0',
                 ),
                 array(            // display 'create_time' using an expression
                  'name'=>'Date Created',
                  'value'=>'date("Y-m-d", $data->created_at)',
                 ),

                 array(            // display a column with "view", "update" and "delete" buttons
                  'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                  'template'=>'{view}{edit}{delete}{expiration_report}',
                   'buttons'=>array
                   (
                       'view' => array
                       (
                           'label'=>'view',
                           'options'=>array('class'=>'btn'),
                           'imageUrl'=>'',
                           'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("",array("collection"=>$data->collection_title))',
                       ),
                       'edit' => array
                       (
                           'label'=>'edit',
                           'options'=>array('class'=>'btn'),
                           'imageUrl'=>'',
                           'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("", array())'
                       ),
                       'delete' => array
                       (
                           'label'=>'delete',
                           'options'=>array('class'=>'btn-danger btn'),
                           'imageUrl'=>'',
                           'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("", array())'
                       ),
                       'expiration_report' => array
                       (
                           'label'=>'expiration report',
                           'options'=>array('class'=>'btn'),'imageUrl'=>'',
                           'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("", array())'
                       ),
                   )
                 ),
              ),
          ));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the attribute in the sort attributes array:

```
$dataProviderInActive->sort->attributes['collection_title']=array(
                                   'asc'=>'collection_title',
                                   'desc'=>'collection_title DESC');
```

Comment: As @marooned says, you should add more details of your code to help you

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have the full details. If this is a custom field, you will have to explicitly define the sorting based on the object type. For example, I did this for CArrayDataProvider objects, and here it is. You will need to do this in your model. Again, the answer will depend on the object type. In my example, $rawData was the returned data from a database query.

```
return new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array(
        'id'=>'id',
        'sort'=>array(
            'attributes'=>array(
                'attribute1',
                'attribute2',
            ),
        ),
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>50,
        ),
    ));
```

Comment: I asked CLinkColumn not sortable any way enable sort for this column